# Should I include another column here to keep track of cost + tax or not?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am making a two database tables tho add a sales order line item functionality to my application.  On the second table, which lets  call `salesorderlineitems`, I have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE salesorderlineitems (
    other columns here,
    units INT(11),
    costPerUnit DECIMAL(11,2),
    totalCost DECIMAL(11,2),
    tax DECIMAL(11,2)
);
```

Now I realized after some developing that besides `totalCost` being sort of a misnomer since it's only `costPerUnit * units`, and not including the `totalCost`.  That made me think, should I change the name of `totalCost` to say `totalUnitsCost` and have `totalCost` be `costPerUnit*units + tax`.

That made me think well I can always just calculate that manually by doing `totalUnitcost + tax`, so why bother saving it.  But then I started thinking of well that's also true of `totalUnitsCost` since it's definition is just multiplication of two other columns.

I know my use case here is pretty simple but I'm sure this concept has popped up in many peoples databases.  Is it worth it to have a column that is just a calculation between two other columns, and under what conditions is it so?  Also, how would I document this if say I choose to go the other route and and only keep track of `units` `costPerUnit` and `tax` and leave the rest up to doing some intra-query calculations, and under what conditions would this be preferable?

Comment: In this case I don't think there is an advantage to storing the calculated value. This is such a simple calculation that just adding it in a SELECT statement should produce virtually no speed loss. If it was a super-complex calculation or there were millions of records it might be helpful to store the calcualted value, but I think you should be fine without it.

Comment: Sure and I realize too this might be the point of a `view`?  But I was curious, as I've come across this a lot in the database at work, times where it's stored and times when it's calculated, and I was just thinking more generally when is an appropriate use case for each?

Answer (score 3):

This is a *legal* question.  The database schema should mimic what the laws mandate.

Since the tax_rate can change all too often, you really should include the rounded value of `tax` in the table.

On the other hand, `total_cost` is necessarily equal to subtotal of cost and `tax`, you should not include it.  A general rule in schema design is not to include any redundant data; that includes readily computable values.

Another thing to think about is "when" the tax is computed.  In some types of stores, the tax *must* be calculated from the subtotal.  In other types of stores, the laws may require computing the tax on each item (or multiple of items).

Perhaps you need a boolean flag called `taxable`.

Some laws say that some items are taxed and some are not.  For example, in California, food generally does not incur sales tax.  But a grocery store often sells non-food items, so there are two subtotals: "taxable" and "non-taxable".  To further confuse things there was, briefly, a "junk food tax" on various 'foods'.

Then comes "VAT" -- which seems to be reverse-computed from the total that the customer pays.

Comment: I do have a `taxable` boolean flag column.  However, I was unaware about the legal issue.  The (small) company I work at is trying to move all their stuff out of real accounting software into our inhouse application and then strictly use that going forward when its ready.  What term can I search to learn more about the legal side of this and what stuff I legally need to store in my database for my state?

Comment: @bjk116 - The state may not talk specifically about "databases" (they possibly still have mechanical calculators on their desks), but they should have a brochure on the requirements of calculating and reporting sales tax.  That is the "legal" issue I was referring to.